# Looping through values in NSDictionary throws fault

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have a plist file that I am loading into an NSDictionary *setDictionary that contains a set of fields, pictureDesc1, pictureDesc2, etc.

Once the NSDictionary is loaded, I can retrieve a value using

```
[setDictionary objectForKey:@"pictureDesc1"];
```

But I cannot do a loop like this:

```
for (int i=1; i<=numberOfPictures; i++) {
    NSString *keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"pictureDesc%d",i];
    NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [setDictionary objectForKey:keyName]];
}
```

Is there a different way to dynamically call keys from within an NSDictionary?

Comment: Except that you are not using the value of description, there isn't anything wrong with doing it like this.

Comment: There's no reason this won't work. What specific problem are you encountering?

Comment: Why not load all of the keys (from the plist file) into an array then get the key index in the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you keys fit a numerical pattern, then it would be easier and more robust to simply store them in a array. You could even store an array as a value in the dictionary with the key of "pictureDescription".

Then when you wanted to loop through them just use a simple numerical loop:

```
NSArray *pictArray=[setDictionary valueForKey:@"pictureDescription"];
NSString *description;
for (i=0;i<[pictArray count];i++){
    description=[pictArray objectAtIndex:i];
    //... do whatever
}
```

If you find yourself shoehorning the functionality of an array into a dictionary or vice versa you probably should back out and just use an array or dictionary in the first place. When using a dictionary, just use an enumerator to step through the values.